# Zebra Printer SDK swift

Tags: swift, zebra-printers, bridging-header

I am currently trying to write an App, that connects to a Zebra printer using Swift. I followed [these](https://km.zebra.com/resources/sites/ZEBRA/content/live/WHITE_PAPERS/0/WH35/en_US/GettingStartedAppleiOSDevelopment_Link-OS_SDK.pdf) instructions to link the SDK to the project and [this page](https://developer.zebra.com/thread/31856) for information on what to add to the bridging header.

This is where it fails. As soon as I add a single line to the bridging header, for example `#import "SGD.h"` it does not compile, with the error `'SGD.h' file not found` [image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out: This was not very clear from the instructions, but I configured those settings in The Project settings, not the Target settings.[image: photo] I also had to disable Bitcode.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question was already self answered by the writer, but... It doesn't answer the question of how to correctly add the Zebra sdk to a Swift project (which is nowhere to be found on Zebra's site or in the documentation).

1. Add the framework ".a" file (libZSDK_API.a) to your project.
2. Add the entire "include" folder provided by Zebra (make sure to add as group)
3. Add a bridging header
4. All of that was pretty standard, now here is the tricky part. Add the following imports to the bridging header **in this exact same order**:

   ```
   #import "MFiBtPrinterConnection.h"
   #import "ZebraPrinterConnection.h"
   #import "ZebraPrinter.h"
   #import "ZebraPrinterFactory.h"
   #import "TcpPrinterConnection.h"
   #import "SGD.h"
   ```